# jquery sortable - reassigning conscutive element IDs on change

Tags: jquery, list

I adding new form elements into a sortable list. When the list is rearranged, I'd the like ID's to be consecutive. Code so far:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection(); 

var counter = 1; 

    $('a').click(function () {
    var elems = '<li>'
    '<input name="q_' + counter + '" type="text"/>' +
    '<select name="type_' + counter + '" >
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>' +
    '</li>' ;
    $('#sortable').append(elems);    


    counter++;    
    return false;


});
```

This produces a list with consecutive IDs, which go out of sync when rearranged. How can I use jquery to iterate through the list and reassign element IDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the function inside the `update` callback

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      $('select').each(function(index){
         $(this).attr('id', index + 1);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: just to clarify: `change` updates the IDs while you sort (might cause overhead if you don't need it) while `update` would update the IDs when you release the mouse button ending the sorting

Comment: This works great. slight modification to work with my code: $('select').each(function(index){
         $(this).attr('name', 't_' + index);
      });

Comment: the '+ 1' is redundant - created 01, 11, 21, 31 etc.

Comment: the + 1 was to make it start from 1, but since you appended it to a string it just got concatenated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `change` event for this.

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
   change: function(event, ui) {
      // reset all the IDs
      $.each($('select'), function(i, v) {
         this.id = "type_" + i; // or the "name" attribute?
      });
   }
});
```